# how to use ajax and flask return value?

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, flask

How can I put the first value of the list in function make progress(i)? list is the value returned from flask!!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Changing the Value of Bootstrap 4 Progress Bar Dynamically</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<style>
    .bs-example{
        margin: 20px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="bs-example">
    <!-- Progress bar HTML -->
    <div class="progress">
        {{rist}}
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped" style="min-width: 20px;"></div>
    </div>

    <form action="/list" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="path" value="{{path}}">
    </form>

    <!-- jQuery Script -->
    <script>
        var i = rist;
        function makeProgress(){
            if(i < 100){
                i = i + 1;
                $(".progress-bar").css("width", i + "%").text(i + " %");
                setTimeout("makeProgress()", 100);
                }
            // Wait for sometime before running this script again
                else { document.forms[0].submit(); }
                $.ajax({

  type:'post',
  async:'true',
  url:'http://127.0.0.1:5000/ ',

  data:{rist},
  dataType: 'json',

  success: function(data){rist
  }
});
        };




    </script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

this is print(rist) // .py

```
list = [(h, e, dictionary[e]) for h, e in zip(category_name, category_id)]
x = []  
for j in list:  
    x.append(j) 
    rist = str(100*(len(x) / len(list)))  
    print(rist)
```

1.1235955056179776
2.247191011235955
3.3707865168539324
4.49438202247191
5.617977528089887
6.741573033707865
7.865168539325842
8.98876404494382
10.112359550561797
11.235955056179774
12.359550561797752
13.48314606741573
14.606741573033707
15.730337078651685
16.853932584269664
17.97752808988764
19.101123595505616
20.224719101123593
21.34831460674157
22.47191011235955
23.595505617977526
24.719101123595504
25.842696629213485
26.96629213483146
28.08988764044944
29.213483146067414
30.337078651685395
31.46067415730337
32.58426966292135
33.70786516853933
34.831460674157306
35.95505617977528
37.07865168539326
38.20224719101123
39.325842696629216
40.44943820224719
41.57303370786517
42.69662921348314
43.82022471910113
44.9438202247191
46.06741573033708
47.19101123595505
48.31460674157304
49.43820224719101
50.56179775280899
51.68539325842697
52.80898876404494
53.93258426966292
55.0561797752809
56.17977528089888
57.30337078651685
58.42696629213483
59.55056179775281
60.67415730337079
61.79775280898876
62.92134831460674
64.04494382022472
65.1685393258427
66.29213483146067
67.41573033707866
68.53932584269663
69.66292134831461
70.78651685393258
71.91011235955057
73.03370786516854
74.15730337078652
75.28089887640449
76.40449438202246
77.52808988764045
78.65168539325843
79.7752808988764
80.89887640449437
82.02247191011236
83.14606741573034
84.26966292134831
85.39325842696628
86.51685393258427
87.64044943820225
88.76404494382022
89.8876404494382
91.01123595505618
92.13483146067416
93.25842696629213
94.3820224719101
95.50561797752809
96.62921348314607
97.75280898876404
98.87640449438202
100.0

and it is my flask code

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from maratang import search 
    
app = Flask(__name__)
    
@app.route('/')
def test():
    return render_template('post.html')

@app.route('/progress', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def loding():
    global result, path, list, error
    if request.method == 'POST':
        result = request.form 
        path = request.form['path'] 
        list, error, rist = search(path)

        return render_template('progress.html', rist = rist)

@app.route('/list', methods=['POST'])
def post():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(list)
        return render_template("result.html", result = result, list = list, error = error)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

I thought it was right, but there was an error, so I don't know what to do.

Comment: What was the error. In success in ajax call now data is equal to your rist. Also I don't see you doing anything with list. You defined rust without getting it in the first line of javascript. They will give error.

Comment: POST /kist HTTP/1.1" 200 - These errors are printed.

Comment: So I tried these methods. However, an error still occurs.

Comment: dataType: 'json' or dataType:'text' or dataType:'all' 
What should I do?

Comment: that's not an error. you are messing all the things. I think you want to show a progress bar which is coming from flask?